# Calling ajax manually by javascript to save name in file

Tags: asp.net

i am sending a name as a query string asynchronously using javascript, that will be saved in the file, i don't want to use jquery for some reasons. But the code is not working. Please help.

**NameTest.aspx**

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Name: "></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp :Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" OnClientClick="AJAX()" Text="Submit" />

</div>
</form>

<script>

function AJAX()
{
var http;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
http = new XMLHttpRequest();
}

http.open("GET", "AJAXHandler.aspx?name=marium", true);
http.send(null);

}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**MyHandlerFile**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.IO;

namespace AJAXNewBostonPrac1
{
public partial class AJAXHandler : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"c:/ajax.txt", FileMode.Create);
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);

sw.WriteLine(Request.QueryString["name"].ToString());

sw.Close();
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ohh I forgot to write the return false; statement in the AJAX() function and in the function call too like this: OnClientClick="return AJAX()"